# How to echo variable outside of a function?

Tags: php, function

I have this code that echoes values from an array. I'd like to be able to echo the variable elsewhere in my code though. I've tried wrapping a function around it and echoing the function but I can't get anything to work. Here's the code that I have now...

```
function team(){

if ( ($items = field_get_items('entityform', $entityform, 'field_team_members')) ) {
  $values = array_map($items, function($x) { return $x['value']; });
  $comma_separated = implode(', ', $values);

  foreach ($items as $item) { 
    $members = $prefix . $item['safe_value'];        
    $prefix = ', ';
    echo $members; 
  }
}

}
```

If I simply do `team();` it outputs nothing, as well as `echo team();`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can add the variable you want to echo as a echo value to the function and then use `return team();`, i suppose this should work, even if im unsure.

Comment: Is `$entityform` passed by reference? I'm assuming it's not -- that you're expecting to pass a value to `field_get_items`, and that because of this the `if` is failing (or `$items` is empty).

Comment: Does your array `$items` contains elements?

Comment: It does. If I put this code outside of the function it does everything perfectly. I just need a way to be able to make this code output the data from the array multiple times on my page and I don't want to have to place this chunk of php all over my document :)

Comment: check my updated answer - should fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, so you also could create an array with these elements and use that multiple times on your page? So, create `$members[]` and set `$members[] = $item`. Then you can use in your code `foreach( $members as $member)` as much as you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Your `team` function doesn't return anything which is why `echo team();` doesn't print anything.

See the documentation on functions for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

```
function team(){
    $output = '';
    if ( ($items = field_get_items('entityform', $entityform, 'field_team_members')) ) {
      $values = array_map($items, function($x) { return $x['value']; });
      $comma_separated = implode(', ', $values);

      $prefix = '';
      $members = '';
      foreach ($items as $item) { 
        $members .= $prefix . $item['safe_value'];        
        $prefix = ', ';
      }
      $output = $members;
   }
   return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what i wrote as a comment, i just created a small script:

```
<?php
function team () {
    $string = "hi";
    return $string;
}

echo team();
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions cant work unless until they are called, so you have to call `team();` in some way, once called it will for sure display what ever you are trying to echo. Also above function will not display anything unless you force fully exit in that function. Or return some value.

Comment: yup my mistake, i will revisit it